# Django: how to use a template tag as an arguments for another template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to use a template tag inside another tag that is a custom tag and it gives me this error:

`Could not parse the remainder: '{{message.tags}}' from '{{message.tags}}'`

How can I fix this? TIA for any help!

**template.html:**

```
    <div class="bootstrap-iso">
    {% if messages %}
        <div class="messages ">
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div {% if message.tags %} class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert" {% endif %}>
                    <strong> {% get_message_print_tag {{message.tags}} %}:  </strong>
                    {{ message }}
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}            
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try `{% get_message_print_tag message.tags %}`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using template tags in delemeters "{% %}" you don't have to use "{{}}".

```
<div class="bootstrap-iso">
{% if messages %}
    <div class="messages ">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div {% if message.tags %} class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert" {% endif %}>
                <strong> {% get_message_print_tag message.tags %}:  </strong>
                {{ message }}
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}            
    </div>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

hope this will work.